# Targeting correct viewport for mobile

Tags: android, iphone, meta-tags, viewport

I have the following in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I've also tried using:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) { .... @media screen and (min-width: 321px) {<-- works only on iphone.. android is not 320px.
```

but have had to modify it to..

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 360px) { .... @media screen and (min-width: 361px) { <--- to support iphone & android
```

I've looked through android's docs, and tried setting viewport content to 320, but the content still shows up wrong for android devices.

Could someone please break this down to me?